# Coding Project is outputting everything but values

Tags: c++

I have a coding project I am working on. I finished all the code but for some reason what should output from my string array isn't outputting. So my result is blank. One of my values comes out to 000002381F913E14 which honestly don't understand what it means. I'm fairly new to programming so there are some concepts I haven't learned but would be glad to learn, thank you for your time!

I tried to change my Parse function and also my Add Student function to see if anything is wrong with it  but I tend to get the same result sadly. I don't know if it has to do with a declaration, constructor, etc.

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include "roster.h"
#include "student.h"
#include "degree.h"
using namespace std;

int main
{

Roster classRoster;
const int totalStudents = 5;
const string studentData\[\] = {
"A1,John,Smith,John1989@gm ail.com,20,30,35,40,SECURITY",
"A2,Suzan,Erickson,Erickson_1990@gmailcom,19,50,30,40,NETWORK",
"A3,Jack,Napoli,The_lawyer99yahoo.com,19,20,40,33,SOFTWARE",
"A4,Erin,Black,Erin.black@comcast.net,22,50,58,40,SECURITY",
"A5,Oscar,Aramburo,oarambu@wgu.edu,24,63,63,63,SOFTWARE"

};
    
    for (int i = 0; i < totalStudents; ++i) {
        classRoster.StudentParse(studentData);
       
    }
    
    
    classRoster.printAll();
    classRoster.printInvalidEmails();
    for (int i = 0; i < totalStudents; ++i) {
        classRoster.printAverageDaysInCourse(classRoster.classRosterArray[i]->GetStudentID());
    }
    
    classRoster.printByDegreeProgram(SOFTWARE);
    classRoster.removeStudent("A3");
    classRoster.printAll();
    classRoster.removeStudent("A3");
    
    return 0;   
    
    }
```

roster.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include "degree.h"
#include "student.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Roster {
public:
    
    const static int totalStudents = 5;
    Student* classRosterArray[totalStudents];
    void StudentParse(const string studentData[]);
    void addStudent(string studentID, string firstName, string lastName, string email, int age,
        int daysInCourse1, int daysInCourse2, int daysInCourse3, DegreeProgram degreeProgram);
    void removeStudent(string studentID);
    void printAll();
    void printAverageDaysInCourse(string studentID);
    void printInvalidEmails();
    void printByDegreeProgram(DegreeProgram degreeProgram);
    ~Roster();
private:
    int studentInd = -1;
    
};
```

roster.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "roster.h"
#include "student.h"
#include <string>
#include <sstream>


void Roster::StudentParse(const string studentData[]) {
    size_t id;
    size_t rest;
    string degreeName;

    id = studentData->find(",");
    string studentID = studentData->substr(0, id);

    rest = id + 1;
    id = studentData->find(",", rest);
    string firstName = studentData->substr(rest, id - rest);

    rest = id + 1; 
    id = studentData->find(",", rest);
    string lastName = studentData->substr(rest, id - rest);

    rest = id + 1;
    id = studentData->find(",", rest);
    string email = studentData->substr(rest, id - rest);

    rest = id + 1;
    id = studentData->find(",", rest);
    int age = stoi(studentData->substr(rest, id - rest));

    rest = id + 1;
    id = studentData->find(",", rest);
    int daysInCourse1 = stoi(studentData->substr(rest, id - rest));

    rest = id + 1;
    id = studentData->find(",", rest);
    int daysInCourse2 = stoi(studentData->substr(rest, id - rest));

    rest = id + 1;
    id = studentData->find(",", rest);
    int daysInCourse3 = stoi(studentData->substr(rest, id - rest));

    rest = id + 1;
    id = studentData->find(",", rest);
    degreeName = studentData->substr(rest, id - rest);

    DegreeProgram degreeprogram = SECURITY;
        if (degreeName == "NETWORK") {
            degreeprogram = NETWORK;
    }
        else if (degreeName == "SOFTWARE") {
            degreeprogram = SOFTWARE;
        }
        this->addStudent(studentID, firstName, lastName, email, age, daysInCourse1, daysInCourse2, daysInCourse3, degreeprogram);

}
void Roster::addStudent(string studentID, string firstName, string lastName, string email, int age,
    int daysInCourse1, int daysInCourse2, int daysInCourse3, DegreeProgram degreeprogram) {

    int daysToComplete[3] = { daysInCourse1, daysInCourse2, daysInCourse3 };


    classRosterArray[++studentInd] = new Student(studentID, firstName, lastName, email, age, daysToComplete, degreeprogram);
    

};

void Roster::removeStudent(string studentID) {
    bool studentRemoved = false;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
        if (classRosterArray[i]->GetStudentID() == studentID) {
            studentRemoved = true;
            cout << "Student Removed?" << endl;
            cout << studentRemoved << endl;
            
        }
        else if (classRosterArray[i]->GetStudentID() != studentID) {
            studentRemoved = false;
            cout << "Student with ID not found" << endl;
        }
        
    }
    
}
void Roster::printAll() {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < totalStudents; i++) {
            classRosterArray[i]->print();
    }
}
void Roster::printAverageDaysInCourse(string studentID) {
    int i;
    int averageAmount;
    for (i = 0; i < totalStudents; i++) {
        averageAmount = classRosterArray[i]->GetDaysToComplete()[0] + classRosterArray[i]->GetDaysToComplete()[1] + classRosterArray[i]->GetDaysToComplete()[2];
            cout << averageAmount / 3 << endl;
    }
}
void Roster::printInvalidEmails() {
    int i;
    string emailAddress;

    for (i = 0; i < totalStudents; i++) {
        emailAddress = classRosterArray[i]->GetEmail();
        if (emailAddress.find(" ") || !emailAddress.find("@") || !emailAddress.find(".")) {
            cout << "Invalid Email:" << classRosterArray[i]->GetEmail() << endl;
        }
    }
}
void Roster::printByDegreeProgram(DegreeProgram degreeprogram) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < totalStudents; ++i) {
        if (classRosterArray[i]->GetDegreeProgram() == degreeprogram) {
            classRosterArray[i]->print();
        }
    }
}
Roster::~Roster() {

}
```

student.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "degree.h"
using namespace std;

class Student {
public:
    Student(string studentID, string firstName, string lastName, string emailAddress, int age,
        int daysInCourse[3], DegreeProgram degreeProgram);
    ~Student();
    
    
    /*----------------------------------*/
    string GetStudentID();
    string GetFirstName();
    string GetLastName();
    string GetEmail();
    int GetAge() const;
    int* GetDaysToComplete();
    DegreeProgram GetDegreeProgram();
    /*---------------------------------*/
    void SetStudentId(string studentID);
    void SetFirstName(string firstName);
    void SetLastName(string lastName);
    void SetEmail(string email);
    void SetAge(int age);
    void SetDaysToComplete(int daysToComplete[]);
    void SetDegreeProgram(DegreeProgram degreeprogram);
    void print();

    

private :
    string studentID;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string email;
    int age = {};
    int daysToComplete[3] = {};
    DegreeProgram degreeprogram = {};
};
```

student.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "student.h"
using namespace std;


//Setters
void Student::SetStudentId(string studentID) {
    this->studentID = studentID;
    
}
void Student::SetFirstName(string firstName) {
    this->firstName = firstName;
}
void Student::SetLastName(string lastName) {
    this->lastName = lastName;
}
void Student::SetEmail(string email) {
    this->email = email;
}
void Student::SetAge(int age) {
    this->age = age;
}
void Student::SetDaysToComplete(int daysToComplete[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        this->daysToComplete[i] = daysToComplete[i];
    }
}
void Student::SetDegreeProgram(DegreeProgram degreeprogram) {
    this->degreeprogram = degreeprogram;
}
//Getters
string Student::GetStudentID() {
    return this->studentID;
}
string Student::GetFirstName() {
    return this->firstName;
}
string Student::GetLastName() {
    return this->lastName;
}
string Student::GetEmail() {
    return this->email;
}
int Student::GetAge() const{
    return this->age;
}
int* Student::GetDaysToComplete() {
    return this->daysToComplete;
}
DegreeProgram Student::GetDegreeProgram() {
    return this->degreeprogram;
}
Student::Student(string studentID, string firstName, string lastName, string emailAddress, int age, int daysInCourse[3], DegreeProgram degreeProgram)
{
}
Student::~Student() {

}


void Student::print() {
    cout << "Student ID: " << GetStudentID() << endl;;
    cout << "First Name: " << GetFirstName() << endl;
    cout << "Last Name: " << GetLastName() << endl;
    cout << "Email: " << GetEmail() << endl;
    cout << "Age: " << GetAge() << endl;
    cout << "Days to Complete: " << GetDaysToComplete() << endl;
    cout << "Degree Program: " << GetDegreeProgram() << endl;
};
```

Degree.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


enum DegreeProgram {SECURITY, NETWORK, SOFTWARE};
```

RESULTS I'M GETTING WHEN I RUN THE CODE:

```
Oscar Aramburo
Student ID:
First Name:
Last Name:
Email:
Age: 0
Days to Complete: 000002381F913A14
Degree Program: 0
Student ID:
First Name:
Last Name:
Email:
Age: 0
Days to Complete: 000002381F913B14
Degree Program: 0
Student ID:
First Name:
Last Name:
Email:
Age: 0
Days to Complete: 000002381F913C14
Degree Program: 0
Student ID:
First Name:
Last Name:
Email:
Age: 0
Days to Complete: 000002381F913D14
Degree Program: 0
Student ID:
First Name:
Last Name:
Email:
Age: 0
Days to Complete: 000002381F913E14
Degree Program: 0
Invalid Email:
Invalid Email:
Invalid Email:
Invalid Email:
Invalid Email:
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
Student with ID not found
Student with ID not found
Student with ID not found
Student with ID not found
Student with ID not found
```

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: You don't even need a debugger for this but it would have been nice to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), i.e. get rid of the 95% (no exaggeration) of your code that is not related to the problem. Anway, the issue is when you print `GetDaysToComplete()`, right? And in comparison, `GetAge()` works fine. Now, what could be the difference betweeen both methods, that could explain one is printed fine but not the other?

Comment: `GetDaysToComplete` returns a pointer to an array. When you print that it outputs the address the pointer points to. If you want to print the contents of the array you need to iterate through it and print each element.

Comment: sorry the issue is for all of the code, not just GetDaysToComplete(), the code "should" pull from the original string array and parse the data and then output it from another array. So even Age should be a INT not 0

Comment: You're parsing `studentData[0]` five times.

Comment: Look at the definition of the `Student` constructor. What does it accomplish? (Enable more warnings in your compiler and pay attention to them.)

Comment: The answer to the last question from @molbdnilo is the Student constructor throws away all data passed to it as parameters. It does not set the member variables of the `Student` class at all so expect all strings in that class to be empty.

Comment: I wrote a simple example code to demonstrate the buggy code and fix: [https://ideone.com/HlN4Sf](https://ideone.com/HlN4Sf)